# Can I add additional content to my iPhone-targeted web app when the user clicks on “add to home screen”?

Tags: html, ios, iphone

I developped a website with webapp capability.
Is it possible to add some additional content to this webapp ?

I mean :
My webapp is basically a html/css/js website adapted to iPhone screen & capabilities.
When someone visits this website & click on "add to home screen" button, this website "become" a webapp, with shortcut icon, launchscreen... Etc.

The webapp content is almost the same as my website adapted to iPhone screen & capabilities (+ splashscreen & shortcut icon).

I want to add some more content in my webapp (than in my website ; but not in my website) :
- a string to thanks users who added it to their home screen,
- special or additional content in comparison with the common website,
Etc.

My question is simple :
is it possible ?
How can I do the trick ?

Thanks to all,

Nico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works a charm...

```
<script>

       if (window.navigator.standalone == true) {
         document.write('<p>Welcome Home</p>');
       }else{
         document.write('<p>Tap the + button and choose "Add to Home Screen"</p>');
         document.write('<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="icon@2x.png"/>');
       }

    </script>
```

Comment: What I need is to add some different content to my "webapp" than my website, when user has pressed the "add to home screen button". Thanks for your concern.

Comment: @Nico3D: `window.navigator.standalone` won’t become true immediately after the app is added to the home screen, but when the user launches the app from the home screen, it will be true. This is the best you’re going to be able to do.